# XSLT: Other way of creating a duplicate

Tags: xml, xslt

I got the following XML as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<Telefonliste>
    <Eintrag PNr="p1" >
        <Name>Meier</Name>
        <TelNr Vorwahl="0271">891234</TelNr>
    </Eintrag>
    <Eintrag PNr="p2" >
        <Name>Schmitz</Name>
        <TelNr Vorwahl="0228">870887</TelNr>
    </Eintrag>
</Telefonliste>
```

And the following xsl script for transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/ | * | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=" text() | @* ">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If I use my script, it produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Telefonliste>
    <Eintrag>
        <Name>Meier</Name>
        <TelNr>891234</TelNr>
    </Eintrag>
    <Eintrag>
        <Name>Schmitz</Name>
        <TelNr>870887</TelNr>
    </Eintrag>
</Telefonliste>
```

This is quite near on what I want, but there are the attributes missing...Why are the attributes missing and how can I add them? I don't want to use THE identity transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT. Second question is, how copies the identity transformation attributes? The xsl:copy command does not copy attribute nodes as far as I know.

Comment: If you add the attributes there won't be a difference in your input and output. Identity transform template would work the best here. What are you looking for? And, `xsl:copy` does copy the attributes.

Comment: I am learning XSLT as part of a activity of the university. It has no practical background my question, just for getting deeper know-how of XSLT. I know the identiy, but I don't want to use it here now. As you can read here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_copy.asp , attribute nodes are not copied automaticly. So I think there is something to add, as in my posted XSLT script does not copy the attributes

Comment: @chris000r You need to read that more carefully: it says "*attributes **of the current node** are not automatically copied!*". IOW, `xsl:copy` performs a "shallow copy" of the current node, discarding any child nodes or attributes. It does not apply when the current node itself is an attribute.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for your advise. What does that exactly mean? If my current node is just an elementnode with attributes, it discards the attributes and child nodes. All right. What if my node is an attribute? What does the xsl:copy do? I just do not exactly understand, in which case the attributes are copied.

Comment: If the current node is an attribute, `xsl:copy` will copy it.

Comment: @michael.hor256k, : all right I got it to work. Would that solution okay, or are there any problems?
Template for any element node:
    `<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`  

Template for Text nodes:

`<xsl:template match="text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template> 
`

Template for attributes:

`<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>`

sorry for uggly formatting -.-

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to accomplish here. For example, `select="*|@*|text()"` excludes comments and processing instructions. The *identity transform* template is a well-established design pattern; you must have good reasons to stray from it.

Comment: it is realy only to get more familiar with xslt and querieng the xml tree and get a better feeling for the types of nodes and so on

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the attributes missing and how can I add them?

The attributes are missing because you neither copy them nor create new ones instead. That should also answer the second part; either one of these:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

will re-create the attributes.

However, in order for this to work, you must first apply templates to the attributes. Your current stylesheet does not do that - the instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

applies templates to child nodes, not to attributes.

> The xsl:copy command does not copy attribute nodes as far as I know...

That is incorrect. As explained above, the problem lies elsewhere.

> I dont want to use THE identity transformation

I would question the wisdom of such decision. Your approach is unnecessarily convoluted. Note also that your two templates conflict since both will match an attribute.

Comment: The purpose of that is just getting a deeper know-how of XSLT. I am learning it for the university. As in my script and on the w3 homepage, I read: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying Here is written "The namespace nodes of the current node are automatically copied as well, but the attributes and children of the node are not automatically copied. " So attributes and children of the node are not autoamically copied. So I do not understand what is to do, that it copies them.

Comment: I have addressed this above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941215/xslt-other-way-of-creating-a-dublicate/44941552#comment76859080_44941215

Comment: @chris000r +1 for reading the spec, though note that's version 1.0 and the current version is 3.0. The text you are quoting says that when you apply xsl:copy to an element, the attributes are not copied. But when you apply xsl:copy to an attribute, the attribute is copied.